# C++ default constructor and POD questions when initializing a new object

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, default-constructor

I understand the difference (at least I believe I understand) the difference between a default constructor and a user provided empty constructor and what POD means. However, there are some behaviors I don't quite understand during object initialization:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//POD
struct A {
    int a, b, c;
};

//Not POD
struct B {
    B() {};
    int a, b, c;
};

int main(){

A a = {1,2,3} \\ Case 1. Works, this is how we initialize a POD type
B b1 = {1,2,3} \\ Case 2. Doesn't work, since B is not POD
B b2;          \\ Case 3. Works, call the user provided empty constructor but a, b and c are not initialized
A c{};        \\ Case 4. Works, initialize everything to 0
A d;          \\ Case 5. Doesn't work. This is the case I don't understand
cout << a.a << a.b << a.c << endl;
cout << b1.a << b1.b << b1.c << endl;
cout << b2.a << b2.b << b2.c << endl;
cout << c.a << c.b << c.c << endl;
cout << d.a << d.b << d.c << endl;
}
```

As mentioned above, case 5 is the behavior I don't understand. I was expecting it will call the default constructor and initialize every member to 0. However, I get the compiling error:

Error   C4700   uninitialized local variable 'd' used

Can anyone help me understand why it reports the above error? I am running on Windows and using Visual Studio compiler.

Comment: Technically, this is a warning, treated as an error. Which, such code can't, possibly, throw, due to `d` not being used anywhere, as error suggests. If I fix multiple typos in your example, and include a `main`: [I can't reproduce the issue](https://rextester.com/CHGA37986). Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Where did you learn that a default constructor would zero-initialise `int`s? They don't.

Comment: Note that your `B` constructor does not initialise any members either. The compiler does not know that, so it can't warn you about it.

Comment: Now I see how you're thinking, but you can't call a constructor. `A c{};` does not mean "call the default constructor", it means "value-initialise `c`". `A d;` is the one that actually uses the default constructor (which the compiler knows does nothing - it probably doesn't even exist - which is why it can warn you about it).

Comment: There's a rather painfully complicated set of rules for different sorts of initialization without arguments, each with different conditions under which they occur (and partially overlapping syntax).  Check out [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), and [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

Comment: @molbdnilo I think the default constructor definitely exists because that's all default constructor about( it is provided by the compiler if the user doesn't provide one). Since the compiler know its existence and sees that the values are initialized, it reports an error or a warning.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius entire code snippet provided

Comment: @OptimusPrime It exists *conceptually*, but since there is no observable difference between "does not exist" and "exists and does nothing", a compiler doesn't need to actually generate a default constructor if it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Did you notice where such error was coming from? I bet it's from using `d`, in `cout << d.a << d.b << d.c << endl;`, and **not** during the construction.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I know they are coming from the line you mentioned but that's my question. I thought they should be initialized to 0 but they were not and the error was reported. So I would like to understand why they were no initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Answering another aspect of question, namely a '*PODness*'.

POD is a legacy definition, and it is not really used anymore, as it can't possibly encompass the variety of situations. It is [deprecated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType) in C++20. Instead, various terms are used to discuss the class compatibility with C structs (because in the end, this is all what it is about).

In particular, the most important properties (at least in my view) are:

- [Standard layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType): it is important because, in laymen terms, when class is standard layout, the object can be treated as a sequence of bytes, sent to some other program (potentially written in the different language) and reconstructed from this sequence on the receiving end (after accounting for padding). This play a great role when entity-serialized data is sent over the network or saved to files
- [Trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable): it is important because when class is trivially copyable, one object can be created from another by just memory copying bytes from one object. This plays a great deal in optimizations
- [Trivial type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType), an extension of Trivially Copyable requirement from above: it is important because when class is trivial type, any random sequence of bytes can be viewed as a valid object of the type (after accounting for memory aliasing).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Error C4700 uninitialized local variable 'd' used
> ```
>
> Can anyone help me understand why it reports the above error?

The error means that you've (likely?) read an indeterminate value. The behaviour of reading an indeterminate value is undefined (disregarding certain exception that evidently doesn't apply in your case).

It seems that the compiler has determined that you use the value of (members of) `d` before initialising, and it attempts to help by diagnosing the issue.

Technically, reading an indeterminate value doesn't make the program ill-formed, so it is not allowed to prevent compilation. It may be possible that you've configured your compiler to intentionally violate the standard by refusing to compile in the case of the warning. If you haven't, then this may be a conformance bug in the compiler.

Solution: Don't read indeterminate values. You can value initialisation to initialise to zero, or list initialisation for other values. See for example cases 1, and 4.

---

Minor corrections about nomenclature:

> Case 3. Works, call the user provided empty constructor but a, b and c are initialized to random garbage values

More accurately: The members are not initialised, and are potentially<sup>1</sup> left with indeterminate values.

<sup>1</sup> In your example, you declare variables with static storage. These are initially zero-initialised before the dynamic initialisation. As such, in your example, the members do not have indeterminate values, but zeroes.

> Case 4. Works, initialize everything to 0 by calling the default constructor

`int`s do not have "default constructors". They are value initialised. Value initialisation of `int` is zero initialisation.